# PowerShell - Move file, Rename & Rotate

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to powershell and still learning. I have completed my first script and now trying to add some logging into it. I am able to append to log file OK but stuck on backing up the log and rotating it. This is what I have so far

```
$CheckFile = Test-Path $Logfilepath
IF ($CheckFile -eq $false) {
$Date = (Get-Date).tostring()
$Date + ' - Automonitor log created - INFO' | Out-File -Append -Force $Logfilepath }
Else {
    IF ((Get-Item $Logfilepath).length -gt $Size) {
    Move-Item $Logfilepath -Destination $LogsOldFolder -Force}
    }
```

This is where I am stuck. If the file is bigger than 5MB I need it to move to another folder (which I have in the script) but when moved into that folder I only want to keep the 5 newest files to avoid storage issues. I will need the files named like the below.

```
Automonitor.log.1
Automonitor.log.2
Automonitor.log.3
Automonitor.log.4
Automonitor.log.5
```

Automonitor.log.1 being the newest created file. So I am really baffled on the process I would take and how to rename the files to match the above format and when new file is copied over, to rename all of them again dependent on date created and deleting the oldest so only 5 files ever exist.

I hope that makes sense, if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way:

```
$a = gci $destfolder
if ( $a.count -gt 5)
{
  $a | sort lastwritetime | select -first ($a.count - 5) | remove-item
}
```

This will get you every file older than the first 5.
So, this script doesnt care about the filenames. If you want that, you should Change the `$a = gci $destfolder` part to some Wildcards.

Comment: Thank you for your help Martin. I convinced them the better route is to have one log file instead of 5 separate logs.